# NModBus Serial Master receiving response after write command

Tags: c#, .net, modbus

I aim to create a UI for a ModBus Serial connection using NModBus nugget on dotnet (4.7 and newer versions).
While developing the serial master I got an obstacle on my road. I haven't figured out the way to get every answer from the Write Registers
(https://nmodbus.github.io/api/NModbus.SlaveExceptionCodes.html)

```
private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Open();
        byte slaveId = Decimal.ToByte(numericMBID.Value);//modbus slave ID
        try {
        master.WriteSingleRegister(slaveId, 5000, Convert.ToUInt16(UserCodeText.Text));
        }
        catch (SlaveException slaveex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(slaveex.Message + slaveex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
        }

        port.Close();
    }
```

*(master is IModbusSerialMaster)*

Using try-catch I caught most of the SlaveExceptions (SlaveDeviceBusy, SlaveDeviceFailure, IllegalFunction, IllegalDataValue, IllegalDataAddress). But I am yet to find a way to catch the "Acknowledge" response!

My slave doesn't return acknowledgement response after every write command. It is crucial to know when and which register returns "Acknowledge" response when the command is executed. This means I need a way to read the Slave Response in every situation, not only in the aforementioned.

I would gladly appreciate and deify any help.